# how can i get the data returned from my webservice into my classes using json

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net

Based on http://json2csharp.com/, i have the following classes:

```
public class Meta
{
    public string reason { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class Objects
{
    public int current_workspace { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public bool is_staff { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string last_login { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Objects objects { get; set; }
}
```

How can i get the data inside the various fields of the classes using:

```
public static void GetLoginDetails(string username, string password)
{
    // Customize URL according to geo location parameters
    var url = string.Format(loginUrl, username, password);

    // Syncronious Consumption
    var syncClient = new WebClient();
    var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
    }
}
```

I have tried some examples but the Objects classes fields are empty
NB:  From the debugging , i can see the data inside the **content** variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

to this

```
RootObject myRootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

then you can access any properties of `myRootObject` if it's not null, i.e `myRootObject.meta.reason`, `myRootObject.objects.key`, etc.

Comment: myRootObject is empty there is no data inside the fields of the class

Comment: Can you add some json sample data to your question?